# Varieties parametrizing skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, matrices, projective-geometry, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ and let us consider the projective space $\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2V)$ parametrizing skew-symmetric matrices.

Let $M\in\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2V)$, for any choice of $n-k$ zeros on the diagonal of $M$ we can construct a $k$-minor $M_{i_1,...,i_{n-k}}$ of $M$ by deleting form $M$ the lines and the columns intersecting in the zeros we choosed. Now, $det(M_{i_1,...,i_{n-k}})=0$ gives an equation for the variety $V_k\subseteq\mathbb{P}(\bigwedge^2V)$ parametrizing matrices of rank at most $k-1$.

In this way we get $\binom{n}{n-k}$ eqautions for $V_k$. Are these equations enough to cut out the ideal of $V_k$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The variety you denoted by $V_k$ is the $(k-1)$-secant variety $Sec_{k-1}(\mathbb{G}(1,n-1))$, where $\mathbb{G}(1,n-1)$ is the Grassmannian of lines in $\mathbb{P}(V)$ parametrizing rank two skew-symmetric matrices.

The ideal $I(Sec_{k-1}(\mathbb{G}(1,n-1)))$ is generated in degree $k$ by sub-Pfaffians of size $2k$ of $M$. These sub-Pfaffians are exactly the ones coming from the minors $M_{i_1,...,i_{n-k}}$ you described. For this you may take a look for instance at Section $6$ of this paper:

http://www.math.tamu.edu/~jml/LOvbflat.pdf